# Struts.xml action configuration

Tags: java, xml

If no methods will will be specified for a action , then which method will be called out for that specified class under that action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override execute method in action class. If no method is provided in action tag of struts.xml file, execute method will be called by default.

Suppose this is your struts action tag. HelloWorld is the action class mentioned. No method is specified. Then execute method will be called in action class.

```
<action name="add" class="example.HelloWorld">
    <result name="SUCCESS" type="redirect">HelloWorld</result>
</action>
```

This is HelloWorld action class.

```
public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {

    @Override
    public String execute() {       
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry there should not have been add method. See edit now. If no method is provided, it will call execute. If method is specified, it will call that method.

Comment: if an interceptor calles invocation.invoke, it will go to next interceptor or action but if returns success then where it will go?